# Different Scopes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If we create beans of two class one having singleton scope and other having prototype scope. If singleton bean refers to prototype bean how many instances will be created? What will happen internally?

Comment: An instance of the prototype bean will be created every time when an instance of that bean is required. So, if you have 2 singleton beans that require (depend on) the prototype bean, you will have 2 instances of the prototype bean.

Answer (score 2):

Spring was born as IoC (Inversion Of Control) framework. From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html):

> IoC is also known as dependency injection (DI). It is a process
>   whereby objects define their dependencies, that is, the other objects
>   they work with, only through constructor arguments, arguments to a
>   factory method, or properties that are set on the object instance
>   after it is constructed or returned from a factory method. The
>   container then injects those dependencies when it creates the bean.
>   This process is fundamentally the inverse, hence the name Inversion of
>   Control (IoC), of the bean itself controlling the instantiation or
>   location of its dependencies by using a direct construction of
>   classes, or a mechanism such as the Service Locator pattern.

In your case: if A is singleton object that referrers a B object scoped prototyped, B will be instantiated once, because A will invoke it only a time (during its creation).